# error while setting up tendermint and bigchaindb

Tags: bigchaindb, tendermint

[Screenshot of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/llLYF.png)got this error

Dialed 96484a110e6f599e6ce6baf576200dd62413fc9b@127.0.1.1:26656, but got peer with ID 8fa7169bb839b43a755196db851a14a1c5968462" addr=96484a110e6f599e6ce6baf576200dd62413fc9b@127.0.1.1:26656

dont understand what it is

Answer (score 0):

I work with the BigchainDB dev team and while BigchainDB uses Tendermint, I'm not an expert on it. That said, maybe try getting Tendermint into a fresh state using:

```
tendermint unsafe_reset_all
```

and

```
sudo rm -rf $HOME/.tendermint
```

If that doesn't work, then maybe try asking on one of the Tendermint support channels.

Comment: I've tried that, and followed the whole procedure again, but still got the same error

Comment: What do you get when you enter 
`tendermint show_node_id`

Comment: Also what version of Tendermint are you using?

Comment: member node_id: 96484a110e6f599e6ce6baf576200dd62413fc9b, coordinator node_id: 8fa7169bb839b43a755196db851a14a1c5968462,I am setting up a network of two nodes, I am using tendermint ver: 0.22.8,bigchaindb ver: 2.0.0b3

Comment: It's easiest to have the two nodes running on two different machines, otherwise you have to play games with ports etc. I'm not sure what your setup is. The latest BigchainDB is version 2.0.0b5 so it might help to update to that. Also, as I noted before, I'm not a Tendermint expert and your best bet to get Tendermint help is to ask on one of their support channels.

Comment: Well right now I'm working two different Ubuntus installed on a VMWare,one node in each Ubuntu,right now I don't have an another machine,may be that's the problem

Comment: I'll try updating both tendermint and bigchaindb to the latest versions,maybe that might solve the problem

Comment: BigchainDB doesn't work with the very latest version of Tendermint, yet. Use BigchainDB 2.0.0b5 and Tendermint 0.22.8.

Comment: Ok will do that

Comment: Addrbook.json doesn't write anything when trying to connect,the list of addresses comes empty